# Header Month Text of DatePickerDialog is cropped

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I use DatePickerDialog to choose the date. I customize the style of it, but header month text is cropped whatever the size.
[image: Screenshot]

my style of dialog:

```
<style name="AppTheme.DateDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.DayHeaderTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.MonthHeaderTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DayHeaderTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.MonthHeaderTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>
```

what's wrong with my style ?

Comment: Try removing <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item> this or setting to lower size.

Answer (score 0):

Your text size is to large try to use default text size and remove `<item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>` these line.

Comment: if I remove that line or use small size like 16sp, month will be disappear.